# How can I stop $(window).scroll event with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I'm trying to freeze scroll at a div position till user click, hover another div. After user action, scroll should be released and work normally! But it doesn't work! How can I make scroll work normally after user hover, click on this div? Here is the full code for reference: https://jsfiddle.net/tqwr3hrp/ (tested on chrome)!

```
<div class="stopscroll">click/mouseover here to stop</div> 
<div class="likebox"></div>

$(window).scroll(function(e) {
$('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $('.likebox').offset().top - 100 }, 1000);
}); 

$('.stopscroll').on('tap click mouseover', function(e) {

$(window).off('scroll');

//another attempt
$('html, body').off('scroll');

//and another attempt
$('html, body').stop().animate();

});
```

Comment: You can't "freeze" the scrollbar, that would be annoying behaviour, and browsers don't allow it, the best you can do is remove the scrollbar, or what you're doing, be even more annoying and reset the scroll position.

Comment: Freeze is just a manner to say! I want to keep this user at this div position untill it take a action... As example user should click at div "stopscroll" to make scroll run normally.

Comment: You can probably do that by constantly setting the scrollTop position when the user tries to scroll, but it's unexpected behaviour, as noone else would do something like that, and as such it's probably among the worst things you could do UX-wise

Comment: Wait I think I get what you want: Automatic scroll but if the user hovers scrollstop, well, stop scrolling (and allow "normal" scrolling) until you move your mouse away again, right? That's not such a bad question actually as I can imagine some use for this, for examle a highscore list or so...

Comment: Yes WcPc, this is exactly what I want! I just wanna stop "freeze" and run scrolling normally after user action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code makes that your page actually scrolls automatically:

```
function start_scrolling() {
  $('body').animate({
    scrollTop: $('body').height() - $(window).height()
  }, 10000, 'linear');
}

start_scrolling();
```

This code lets the scrolling stop if you hover your div and lets it start again if you unhover it. Instead of doing the same with `click` I recommend adding a checkbox, which I did in this example. If the checkbox is checked, scroll as usual, if not, let the user scroll himself.

```
$('.stopscroll').mouseover(function() {
  $('body').stop();
}).mouseout(function() {
  if($('#autoscroll').is(':checked')) {
    start_scrolling();
  }
});
```

This last code is a bonus and lets the user take control immediatedly: If the user scrolls, the autoscroll is deactivated. If he wishes to enable the autoscroll again, he can use the checkbox.

```
$('body').on('scroll wheel DOMMouseScroll touchmove', function() {
  $('body').stop();
  $('#autoscroll').prop('checked', false);
});
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tqwr3hrp/4/)